# jQuery Get Value From Dynamically Created Content after .keypress() with .delegate()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this code which seems unable to retrieve the value of particular ID on `.keypress` function after using `.delegate`. The ID and other contents are actually generated dynamically via AJAX call.

```
    $(document).delegate('.edit_tr', 'click', function(){

        var cont_det_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#name_" + cont_det_id).hide(); //hide span
        $("#input_name_" + cont_det_id).show(); //show editable box
        //alert cont_det_id works good and gets correct ID

    }).keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13) { //if statement for pressing enter button
            var cont_det_id = $(this).attr('id');
            //alert cont_det_id gets undefined
        }
    });
```

I am using old template that I was working on previously so the jQuery version is 1.7.x. Anybody has any idea for the workaround? Thanks.

Comment: use `.on` i think `.delegate` is for older version

Comment: basically `.delegate` is working to take the dynamic ID but not after `.keypress`. I am using older version of jQuery so `.on` does not work for me.

Comment: for the keypress also you need to use the delegate method like `$(document).delegate('.edit_tr', 'keypress', function(){});`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I need to put it straight away in `.delegate` or can do function chaining as well?

Comment: @UserProg my bad i thought `.delegates` only works up until 1.2 versions.

Comment: `$(document).delegate('.edit_tr', 'click keypress', function(){` Try this

Comment: @UserProg yes... you can - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6tn1cgqh/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny your solution worked perfectly. I managed to get the ID now. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arun P Johny suggestion in the comment worked for me. So I post it here with hope that this could benefit somebody.

```
$(document).delegate('.edit_tr', 'click', function(){

    var cont_det_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#name_" + cont_det_id).hide(); //hide span
    $("#input_name_" + cont_det_id).show(); //show editable box
    //alert cont_det_id works good and gets correct ID

}).delegate('.edit_tr', 'keypress', function (e) {
    if(e.which == 13) { //if statement for pressing enter button
        var cont_det_id = $(this).attr('id');
        //alert cont_det_id good here
    }
});
```